# Possible to connect securely to remote MySQL using SSIS?

Tags: mysql, ssis

I've downloaded an ADO.NET and ODBC connector from the MySQL website.  I'd like to access a remote MySQL server from within BIDS with the goal of importing the remote data and populating a local SQL Server database.

While it looks like making the connection is relatively easy, does anyone know if it's possible to connect securely so that data is encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is deploying an SSL Certificate an option?

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p31

**Using SSL**

Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername; Password=myPassword;sslca=c:\cacert.pem;sslcert=c:\client-cert.pem;sslkey=c:\client-key.pem;sslverify=1;Option=3;

Also, [Matthew Flaschen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47773/matthew-flaschen) suggests an option here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984208/secure-odbc-connection-oxymoron/984261#984261)

Comment: Thanks.  Deploying a certificate is an option on the MySQL side, but not the SQL Server side.